# Passing parameter to method which implements protocol and extends a class in swift

Tags: ios, templates, generics, swift, protocols

In Objective-C, you can inform the compiler that a type should be a descendent of a specific class, and also conform to a protocol (e.g. "UIViewController *foo = nil").

I'm trying to do something similar with Swift, and it looks like this requires use of generics. Here's what I would expect to work:

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: String {get set}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var foo: String = ""
}

func doAThing<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>(vc: T) -> T? {
    var myViewController: T? = nil

    myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    return myViewController
}
```

The error I get is: 'MyViewController' is not convertible to 'T'. Can I not use generics with "concrete", un-parameterized classes? I'm still wrapping my head around this part of the language, thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the declaration of MyView?

Comment: I edited my post, it should have read MyViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you expect `MyViewController` to be any subclass of `UIViewController` that implements `MyProtocol`  Note that there really isn't a clean way to get back to `UIViewController` methods short of adding anything relevant to the protocol.

I think what you're looking for is:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: String {get set}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var foo: String = ""
}

class MyOtherViewController : UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var foo = "My other view controller"
}

func doAThing<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>() -> T? {
    return T(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

let myViewController : MyViewController? = doAThing()
let myOtherViewController : MyOtherViewController? = doAThing()

let myProtocol : MyProtocol? = myViewController
```

Since swift function overrides are allowed to differ only by return type and the type inference is capable of selecting between them, `doAThing` doesn't really need a parameter in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my specific question above :) The thing I'd like to do also is select and set a specific view controller based on a certain set of rules. I might post a follow up question...

Comment: If the follow up is "How can I declare a reference to UIViewController subclass that implements MyProtocol so I can use viewController.view?" the answer is pretty much "you can't"  Best practice at this point seems to be to add the interesting UIViewController methods to MyProtocol.